# My question was buried too quickly in the questions list

Tags: discussion, question-lists

A couple of minutes ago, I posted a question on Stack Overflow. It was about dynamic programming.

I posted my answer, waited around for approximately two minutes, refreshed the page and realized that all of a sudden IT WAS ON PAGE 3 OF NEWEST QUESTIONS.

I thought to myself..."eh, I was just unlucky...I probably just asked the question at the wrong time." But then, as I scrolled through page after page in Newest Questions, I realized that almost every single one of them was at 0 votes 0 answers!

How would it be possible to prevent such a thing from happening? Placing a restriction on the time between user's questions would definitely help, but it would totally impede the productivity of Stack Overflow.

Do you guys have any other ideas that could help? Obviously I'm in no position to *do anything* with your guys's ideas, but maybe a really good idea will get the attention of moderators?

Comment: Just like on the main site: being new doesn't excuse not doing your research.... if there is a duplicate, did you even try to find it?

Comment: @Patrice Yep I tried for only 10 minutes though :( Is that why I got the downvote?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It's hard to tell. In any case, the fact you DID search is good :). From the phrasing of your question here I wasn't sure. In any case, don't fret for meta votes. They don't impact your rep :). So people have a tendency to downvote more easily on meta :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really *not* possible to prevent something like this from happening.  This is due to the sheer volume of questions that Stack Overflow receives per *minute*, which pushes questions off of the main page fairly quick.

The important thing is to ensure your question is of good quality.  The rest will follow from that.

Comment: ... _good quality_, and tagged appropriately...

Comment: @TinyGiant You've touched on the right point. A LOT of users filter questions by tags, so that makes it harder for questions to "fall off the end".

Answer (score 5):

Like @Makoto said, there is an incredible volume of questions coming into the site per minute.

But, for what it's worth, a lot of the regulars here *filter* questions by tags. This means, they see more of the questions they're interested in viewing, and less questions (or, not at all) from tags they're disinterested in. Users can also add tags to their `Favourite Tags` or `Ignored Tags` lists, further streamlining content.

I also use the increased setting of 50 questions per page, which is the maximum number of questions you can view per page. With that, it takes a LOT longer for questions to fall off the end, and out of my line of sight. I'm sure a lot of other users do this as well.

I can assure you that *people are watching* at all times. If your question is good, demonstrating your efforts at first attempting to solve your problem, then it deserves an answer, and someone will inevitably do so.